CMake: Add presets with Visual Studio 2002 and 2022 generators
I have project that was built using Visual Studio NET (2002) with Visual C++ 7.0
I need to add CMake with ability to generate project for Visual Studio 2002 or latest (Visual Studio 2022) depending on which build you choose (legacy or latest). The first one should use Visual C++ 7 and second one latest version of Visual C++
I started of thinking about CMakePresets and using two presets with Visual Studio 2002 and Visual Studio 2022 generators, but first one is removed from CMake 3.2 I guess.
CMake wiki says: Instead of Visual Studio 2002 generator I should use NMake makefiles. I have no idea how should I make this file to use MSVC 7 compiler, because I don't know how to get path to compiler path without hardcoding.

Does VS2002 come with a (variation of) vsvars.bat? If so, ask your users to run CMake under the scope of that file or set some environment variables before invoking CMake.

All of VS2002 was IIRC buggy ... msvc 7.0, NET 1.0, msvcr?70.dll etc., So it was rapidly replaced with bugfix VS2003 NET 1.1, msvc 7.1 etc.  Insistence of usage something buggy after 20 years have passed smells like bad intentions.

@Botje Yes, I have vsvars32.bat in %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\Common7\Tools. Never heard of this file

@ÖöTiib Unfortunately, The project was made with those tools. The source code was lost, so we have to reverse engineer it. Using those tools is great idea to compare binaries, in my opinion

vsvars.bat populates the environment variables for finding the compiler and other parts of the toolchain. It is also known as the "developer command-line". If you run CMake and/or NMake under that it might pick up the compiler from there. Needless to say, I have no way to reproduce your scenario.

@Botje How can I execute vsvars32.bat from toolchain and set env vars from it?

Other way round. You source the bat file first and in that environment run CMake and/or NMake.

Seems like it's the only way. Big thanks!
